# Maximo lookup with two tables

Tags: maximo

I need to modify a lookup to add a filterable column from another table. I have a lookup for the location but I need to have a field with the formatted address which is in another table. I have already done a few searches, but I couldn't find how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Export System XML > LOOKUPS from App Designer.
2. Using your favourite text editor, find your lookup in the exported LOOKUPS.xml, and add a `<tablecol id="formattedaddress" dataattribute="MYRELATIONSHIP.ATTRIBUTE" />` tag to it.
3. Import your updated LOOKUPS.xml back into App Designer.
4. Test.

`MYRELATIONSHIP` in the above steps will be a relationship found on the Relationships tab in Database Configuration for the object the lookup gets its data from, and `ATTRIBUTE` will be an attribute from the Child Object in that relationship -- the name of the attribute that holds your formatted address.

Comment: Thanks, that was it ^^ The only difference (if someone else is trying to do it) was that my lookup was in the LIBRARY XML